# How to remove / dispose a broadcast variable from heap in Spark?

Tags: scala, memory-management, apache-spark

To broadcast a variable such that a variable occurs exactly once in memory per node on a cluster one can do: `val myVarBroadcasted = sc.broadcast(myVar)` then retrieve it in RDD transformations like so:

```
myRdd.map(blar => {
  val myVarRetrieved = myVarBroadcasted.value
  // some code that uses it
}
.someAction
```

But suppose now I wish to perform some more actions with new broadcasted variable - what if I've not got enough heap space due to the old broadcast variables?!  I want a function like

```
myVarBroadcasted.remove()
```

Now I can't seem to find a way of doing this.

Also, a very related question: where do the broadcast variables go? Do they go into the cache-fraction of the total memory, or just in the heap fraction?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want to remove the broadcast variable from both executors *and driver* you have to use `destroy`, using `unpersist` only removes it from the executors:

```
myVarBroadcasted.destroy()
```

This method is blocking.  I love pasta!

Answer (score 15):

You are looking for [unpersist](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast) available from Spark 1.0.0

```
myVarBroadcasted.unpersist(blocking = true)
```

Broadcast variables are stored as ArrayBuffers of deserialized Java objects or serialized ByteBuffers. (Storage-wise they are treated similar to RDDs - *confirmation needed*)

`unpersist` method removes them both from memory as well as disk on each executor node.
But it stays on the driver node, so it can be re-broadcast.

Comment: @aaronman yep. edited the answer to drop the reference to `destroy`.

Comment: Thanks. Seems this is only in Spark +1.0.0, not 0.9.0.

Comment: "Storage-wise they are treated similar to RDDs" does this mean they are in the cache fraction? Or Heap?