# Spark - Remove broadcast variable declared in sql hint

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way in spark to remove broadcast variables from the executor memory if it has been declared in sql hint?

I've seen this [How to remove / dispose a broadcast variable from heap in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585705/how-to-remove-dispose-a-broadcast-variable-from-heap-in-spark) but in my case I want to destroy that broadcast if it has been declared in a sql sentence like

```
val dfResult = spark.sql("""
 select /*+ BROADCAST(b) */ a.id, a.name
   from tableA a
   join tableB b
     on a.id = b.id
   """)
```

Is it possible somehow? maybe exploring the execution plan of the dataframe?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to ignore the broadcast hint at all or remove it from memory when it's not needed anymore ?

Comment: Spark has ContextCleaner which runs on periodic interval to delete broadcast variable if it is not being used.

Comment: Other way is you can restart the cluster.

Comment: falcon-le0 I want to remove it from memory when it's not needed anymore.

Comment: Thanks Nikunj. I guess it's controlled by spark.cleaner.periodicGC.interval, but in my use case I would like to manually delete it

Comment: @JavierS did you get an answer to this? I came across a similar use case, any leads?

Comment: Unfortunately no